# How does shared checkout behave with multiple store domains?

Tags: multistore, setup

We're setting up Magento to run 1 website and 3 stores each with 1 store view.  Each store view is associated with a different domain.  Since the 3 stores are part of 1 website, the catalog will be shared between the 3 stores, as well as the checkout (ie: if you add a product in store 1 you can checkout with that product in store 2).  However, the look and feel of these stores is totally different.

The question I have is, since the checkout is shared, will Magento try to redirect from store 2 and 3 to store 1 to complete the checkout?  Or even though the checkouts are shared, will pressing checkout on store 2 complete the checkout using store 2's domain and templates, likewise pressing checkout on store 3 will complete the checkout using store 3's domain and template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be forced to store 1 when pressing checkout on store 2 or 3, unless you write some code telling Magento to do so.
Also when doing a checkout process on any store you will get the look and feel of that specific store.
You can take a look at the [magento demo](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/). Add a product to the cart, do a checkout, then switch the store from the bottom switcher (to modern theme for example) and repeat the process.